# Variable not usable when if-statement is used inside a method

Tags: ruby

My code is working correctly when I don't define my if statement as a method. However, when I do, I'm getting the error below

```
in `verify': undefined local variable or method `guess' for main:Object (NameError)
```

This is the code I'm working with

```
def verify
  if guess > answer
    puts "Sorry! Too high."
  elsif guess < answer
    puts "Sorry! Too low."  
  else
    puts "Congratulations! You guessed it!"
  end  
end

answer = 5
puts "What is your guess?"
guess = gets.to_i
verify
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is what's called `scope`. Inside the method, `guess` and `answer` are not defined unless you pass them in as arguments.

To fix it, this would work:

```
def verify(guess, answer)
  if guess > answer
    puts "Sorry! Too high."
  elsif guess < answer
    puts "Sorry! Too low."  
  else
    puts "Congratulations! You guessed it!"
  end  
end

answer = 5
puts "What is your guess?"
guess = gets.to_i
verify(guess, answer)
```

Note that the method arguments don't need to be called like that, they can have any valid name, but then you of course have to change the method body accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! Couldn't figure out how to pass those in other than as global variables, which I'd read is not advised.

Comment: Maybe read this and please accept the answer to let others know that this solved your problem: http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/scope.html